# How to loop a SQL query, using variables within the query, and write to a table in Microsoft Access

Tags: sql-server, loops, variables, ms-access-2016

I have SQL code that I run in SSMS that utilizes a query and two date variables to examine month over month changes in a table. The first part of the query uses @month1 as it's date variable in the WHERE statement and the second part of the query uses @month2.

DECLARE
@month1 INT = 0
@month2 INT = 1

Each time the query is ran within my WHILE loop, the variables are increased by 1 using the SET command:
SET @month1 = @month1 + 1
SET @month2 = @month2 + 1

So in essence, the query examines January data to February data. Loop occurs and the query examines February data to March data...and so on until a predefined counter variable value is reached and it exits the loop. Within the loop, I am appending records into a temp table.

The code runs perfectly in SSMS, however, I would like to use it in Microsoft Access so that other non SSMS users can execute. I haven't been able to find any examples so far. Would a function be necessary or can Access utilize my sql script that I have saved? Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated!

Update: Here is a sample of the loop code just for reference.

```
DECLARE
@month1 INT = 0,  
@month2 INT = 1,  
@effdate DATETIME = '01/15/2021'  

`` # of Loop iterations
WHILE @month1 <= 8  
BEGIN

`` Find moves from a specific plan type to another plan type
INSERT INTO #PlanChanges
        ([blah],[blah],[blah],[blah],[blah],[blah],[Change_Type], 
        [Change_Period], [MonthNum])

Select [blah],[blah],[blah],[blah],[blah],[blah],
    CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20), 'LOSS OF PLAN'), DATENAME(MONTH, Plan2.EFF_DT)  + ' ' + DATENAME(YEAR, Plan2.EFF_DT),
    DATEPART(Month, Plan2.EFF_DT)
    
From  (Select *
       From MONTHLY_MEMBERSHIP TABLE
       Where PLAN_ID = '714'
       AND EFF_DT = CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(MONTH, 
       DATEADD(MONTH,@month1, @effdate)), 101) + '/15/' + 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(MONTH,@month1, @effdate)), 
       101) )) AS Plan1

Inner Join  (Select *
             From MONTHLY_MEMBERSHIP TABLE
             Where (PLAN_ID >='700' AND EFF_DT = CONVERT(DATETIME, 
             CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH,@month2, 
             @effdate)), 101) + '/15/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(YEAR, 
             DATEADD(MONTH,@month2, @effdate)), 101) ))
             AND PLAN_ID <> '714') AS Plan2

    ON  Plan1.MEM_ID = Plan2.MEM_ID

`` change the loop conditions
SET @month1 = @month1 + 1
SET @month2 = @month2 + 1
    
END
```

Comment: OK 1 you can do this without loops in 1 single statement, which i strongly suggest that you investigate. 2 you can use a pass thru query in Access to do this in SQL Server. That way non SSMS users can still get the heavy lifting from SQL Server but from Access you UI.

Comment: Without seeing your code, cannot advise, but a loop is probably the wrong way to do this

Comment: Doug Coats is right, if you are in a loop in SQL code, try your best to write it another way

Comment: Hello All, appreciate everyone taking the time to leave a comment and suggestions. Doug Coats, can you provide an example of how you would accomplish that without using a loop? Curious to see your approach.